# Full width of input field in a inline-block not working

Tags: css, wordpress, width, auto

Issue: 
image.png

The drop-down menu is showing "Choose an option" like a box that comes out of the text area. I did my little research and it is a CSS issue and followed the instructions.

I right-click on the "Choose an option" and click on "inspect" as shown below:

[image: Issue 1]

The highlighted code is where the error is and if I change the "width" in the code to "150px" or "Auto" then the option appears accurately as below

[image: Issue 2]

This needs to be added to the Custom CSS code in my WordPress Custom CSS tab which I did as below

[image: Issue3]

But it does not change after I hit Publish. That is my glitch. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Maybe I am not choosing the CSS Class correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! it looks nice how you have described the issue, but to get help you either have to add code here or should show what you have done to fix this.

Comment: I tried various combination of the class names and still do not get the result. Kindly help

Comment: Thank you, I am providing the code below:

Comment: <span class="theme-select" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="theme-selectInner" style="width: 38px; display: inline-block;">Choose an option</span></span>      </td> <span class="theme-select" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="theme-selectInner" style="width: 38px; display: inline-block;">Choose an option</span></span>

Comment: In the above code, I change the width : 150 px and it works on the inspect window

Comment: but when I add the code in the Additional CSS in wordpress customize, It does not change

Comment: can you share both html and css code as well? but not in comments instead in the question

Comment: @arvindaceshigh you have an answer. The inline styling is overwriting your class. I don't know why WS is doing that so if you really want to get better with WS, you should probably investigate why that is happening as well. But anyway the aswer should help you to make it work for now.

Answer (score -1):

You should have inspected the element to be sure, but my guess is that, for some reason, wordpress is initialing the inline style of the element to 36px. 
That overwrites the class styling (you can read more about css priorities [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)).

As an easy fix you could just use `important!` rule. You should be carefully to use it only when is really necessary (you can read more about [here](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)).

I really recomand to only use important when you really need it, since it can easily backfire otherwise.

Comment: https://rabbagash.com/product/clearance-scoyco-cow-leather-motorcycle-boots-men-motocross-boots-off-road-racing-boots-professional-motorcycle-shoes/

Comment: If you create a class let's say `full-with` , you set it like this in the css: `.full-with { witdth: 100%!important;}` than give your elements this class, it should work.

Comment: Hi Berci,    https://rabbagash.com/product/clearance-scoyco-cow-leather-motorcycle-boots-men-motocross-boots-off-road-racing-boots-professional-motorcycle-shoes/          That is the link to the page, is it possible for you to inspect it please? That way, you can see the whole code. I am very new to coding and watching tutorials to get this sorted. Thank you

Comment: I can follow your instructions, I am unaware on hot to go about even creating a class... sorry

Comment: That is really hard to answer since I can only see the generated code. I don't know if you use a theme or what acces you have to modify it. You should be able to create a class just by opening the `Customizing additional css ` tab and copying `.full-with { witdth: 100%!important;}`. Than add it to you html elements.

Comment: Thank you Barci, I will try it out now.